# Is there a Cocoapod that allows me to see the closest version of a business and their phone number?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, google-location-services

I know when you google a business, it shows the where the closest stores are located and the phone number for that specific location. Is there a version of this in the form of a cocoapod?

Comment: Use Google Places SDK.

Answer (score 1):

I think you answered you own question.   Why not use googles official sdk's/cocoapods?

https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/intro

https://cocoapods.org/pods/GooglePlaces

You'll be able to search for places and display whatever information you see fit.